# Compiler not liking UIScrollViewDelegate with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an error, when implementing a `UIScrollView` into a  `UITableViewCell`.

```
class MyItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {

...  

var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scroll = UIScrollView()
        scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scroll.delegate = self
        return scroll;
        }()

...

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
     ...   
    }

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView!, velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: CMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
     ...   
    }
...
}
```

The compiler gives me an error on the line `scroll.delegate = self` saying that the `Type MyItemTableViewCell does not conform to protocol ‘UIScrollViewDelegate’`

Never mind the fact, that the methods in the protocol are all documented as optional (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html), but I have two implemented.

What does the compiler want from me?

Thanks

Comment: Change `targetContentOffset` to type inout CGPoint?

Comment: @JackWu: Tried that - no luck. :-(

Comment: @David: I modeled it according to the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the init cycle, self isn't usable until all properties have been initialized.  Change it to:

```
class MyItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
    }

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView!, velocity: CGPoint, inout targetContentOffset: CGPoint) {
    }

    init() {
        scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        super.init(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: `inout X:T` is a synonym for `X:CMutablePointer<T>` so use whichever is more comfortable for you.

Comment: can I call the func scrollViewDidScroll within my ViewController?

Comment: @LiamShalon You can, although you might want to consider extracting the functionality into a non-delegate method that you invoke directly and from `scrollViewDidScroll`

Comment: however, how would I implement the function in the ViewController?