# Detecting Swipe Gestures on TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

Is there a way to detect up & down swipes on TableView in a ViewController?

in `ViewDidLoad()`;

```
    let upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipeUp:"))
    let downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipeDown:"))

    upSwipe.direction = .Up
    downSwipe.direction = .Down

    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

```
func swipeDown() {
    print("A")     
}
```

nothing returned.

What is the appropriate way to detect gestures on TableView (not cell/as a whole)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView Scroll event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642699/uitableview-scroll-event)

Comment: @BLE I was asking for Swift

Comment: Apologies, but it's mostly semantics.  The information you're looking for is in the UIScrollViewDelegate portion of the documentation on developer.apple.com  `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)`

Comment: @BLE I tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24166783/4705339) but couldn't make it work :/ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about it didn't work?  Did you put anything inside `func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
    }` ?

Comment: It doesn't let me use `super.init(nibName:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, bundle:"MyCell")`.. It doesn't let me bypass this line.. So I can't build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement UIScrollViewDelegate

Define `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)`

Set your tableview's scrollview's delegate to whatever object you've got the above defined in.

Comment: This line crashes `super.init(nibName:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, bundle:"MyCell")`` for some reason. I setup `var scrollView: UIScrollView`, added Delegate and then included `scrollViewDidScroll` & `scrollViewWillEndDragging`.. The init part still crashes.. I don't know if it matters but, I have TableView, not TableViewController

Comment: presumably your code in your original question was written in UITableViewController, no?

Comment: No, it's a TableView inside ViewController. `class TrialViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate`; so I tried adding `UIScrollViewDelegate`, but at this point, it needed initialisers. Using the `init` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24166783/4705339) gives error.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. All I needed was to add `scrollViewDidScroll` function and no delegate. Ahh.... Thanks